# Proving a set defined using the norm is compact

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, compactness

I'm currently stuck on the following question

Let be $ \|  \|$ be any norm on $\mathbb{R}^m$ and let $B = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^m : \| x \| \leq 1\}$. Prove that B is
compact.

I've shown that this set is bounded but I can't seem to show that it's closed. Can someone give me a hint to start off?

Comment: Apologies. Made an error typesetting it. I've fixed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your set is $B=\{x\in\Bbb R^m\mid\|x\|\leqslant1\}$, then it is closed because, if $n\colon\Bbb R^n\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is the norm, then $n$ is continuous, $B=n^{-1}\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$, and $[0,1]$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

If $y\notin B$, then the ball of positive(!) radius $|y|-1$ around $y$ is disjoint from $B$. Hence the complement of $B$ is open and $B$ itself closed.